# Stop Motion Animation CSS

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am creating a stop-motion animation of a running cat. I have already all the slides ready. But it doesn't seem to work properly:

```css
div {
  animation: run 1s steps(10) infinite;
  -webkit-animation: run 1s steps(10) infinite;
  background: url(http://stash.rachelnabors.com/img/codepen/tuna_sprite.png) 0 0; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
}

@keyframes run {  
  0% {background-position: 100% 0; } 
  100% {background-position: 100% -2591px; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes run {  
  0% {background-position: 100% 0; } 
  100% {background-position: 100% -2591px; }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Here is the explanation on how to do this. [link](http://24ways.org/2012/flashless-animation/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually you have 13 slides. So put `steps(13)`

```css
div {
  animation: run 1s steps(13) infinite;
  -webkit-animation: run 1s steps(13) infinite;
  background: url(http://stash.rachelnabors.com/img/codepen/tuna_sprite.png) 0 0; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
}

@keyframes run {  
  0% {background-position: 100% 0; } 
  100% {background-position: 100% -2591px; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes run {  
  0% {background-position: 100% 0; } 
  100% {background-position: 100% -2591px; }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: hosted image has four type of slide shot how do i change style there (cat running style) i mean image marging

Comment: Its all a play of `background-position`. In `@keyframes`, change the `x` coordinate of the `background-position`

Comment: You'll have to adjust the height and no. of steps similarly.

Comment: Thanks @Mr_Green! All CSS was Timbatu's. Just the `steps()` part.